# Вызов функции повторяетcя несколько раз js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, бот, асинхронность

Пишу бота.
Задача: на команду пользователя исполнить функцию - прислать ему сообщение, получить ответ, в зависимости от ответ выполнить действие.
Проблема: на первую команду пользователя всё отрабатывает корректно. На повторную аналогичную команду, корректно выполняется только первая часть, дальше идёт задвоение.
Пример кода и результата:

```
...
if (text === '/add) {
       await bot.sendMessage(tgchat, `Choose category`)
       bot.on('message', async msg => {
            if (text === 'k') {
                 return bot.sendMessage(tgchat, "received")                        
                  }
}
...
```

Если ввести /add один раз - 1:бот пришлет 'Choose category' 2:при ответе сообщением 'k' 3:пришлет 'received'

Но если ввести /add повторно - 1:бот !один раз! пришлет 'Choose category' 2:но при ответе сообщением 'k' 3:!дважды! пришлет 'received'.  И так далее ...

Как это исправить, уже немало времени пытаюсь...

Comment: Потому что вы каждый раз вешаете ЕЩЕ ОДИН обработчик

Comment: Справедливо.
Но как без обработчика получить и проверить ответ пользователя?

Comment: Повесьте обработчик один раз. Например когда пользователь подключается

Comment: Были такие мысли, напрасно гнал их от себя.
Вы правы, всё отлично работает, статусы пользователя проверяю через бд, спасибо!